# Segfault with thread_local and std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, thread-safety

During a debugging session, I found a problem that I was able to reduce down to this C++11 code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(){
            printf("%p\n", this);
        }
        ~MyClass(){
            printf("~%p\n", this);
        }

        std::unordered_map<int, int> member;
};

thread_local MyClass threadLocalObject;

int main(){
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i){
        threads.emplace_back([&](){
            printf("%ld\n", threadLocalObject.member.size());
        });
    }

    for (auto &thread : threads)
        thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler I use is `g++-6 (Homebrew GCC 6.4.0) 6.4.0` on `MacOS 10.12.6`.
The problem is that it seems to crash inside the destructor of `member`.

It doesn't always crash, though, which makes me wonder if it's some kind of race condition between the threads.

Any help is appreciated, this drives me insane.

I had similar crashes with MinGW on Windows, so I really hope to gain some knowledge from someone who understands what is going on here.

This is one of the more drastic crashlogs of this code:

```
0x7f9b2ba00228
0x7f9b2ac02728
0x7f9b2ba004e8
0x7f9b2ae00128
0x7f9b2b800128
0x7f9b2ad00128
0x7f9b2ac025f8
0x7f9b2ad00178
0x7f9b2b900138
0x7f9b2b800288
0x7f9b2ad002d8
0x7f9b2b900188
0x7f9b2ba00388
0x7f9b2b800548
0x7f9b2b8003e8
0x7f9b2b800cd8
0x7f9b2af00898
0x7f9b2ba00a68
0x7f9b2ae00ad8
0x7f9b2af00c08
0x7f9b2b900918
0x7f9b2ba00dd8
0x7f9b2b801048
0x7f9b2ae00e48
0x7f9b2b8013b8
0x7f9b2b801728
0x7f9b2af00f78
0x7f9b2ba00538
0x7f9b2af012e8
0x7f9b2b9002e8
0x7f9b2af00268
0x7f9b2ae004a8
0x7f9b2b900338
0x7f9b2af003c8
0x7f9b2ae00608
0x7f9b2af00528
0x7f9b2ae00768
0x7f9b2ae008c8
0x7f9b2af00688
0x7f9b2af006d8
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
~0x7f9b2ba00228
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
~0x7f9b2ac025f8
~0x7f9b2ad00178
~0x7f9b2ad00128
a.out(32726,0x70000e123000) malloc: *** error for object 0xa38333130303962: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
~0x7f9b2b900138
~0x7f9b2ad002d8
a.out(32726,0x70000e2ac000) malloc: *** error for object 0xa38633830306561: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
~0x7f9b2ba00388
~0x7f9b2b800288
~0x7f9b2b800548
~0x7f9b2b8003e8
~0x7f9b2b800cd8
~0x7f9b2af00898
~0x7f9b2ba00a68
~0x7f9b2ae00ad8
~0x7f9b2af00c08
~0x7f9b2b900918
~0x7f9b2ba00dd8
~0x7f9b2ae00e48
~0x7f9b2b801048
~0x7f9b2b8013b8
~0x7f9b2b801728
~0x7f9b2af00f78
~0x7f9b2ba00538
~0x7f9b2af012e8
~0x7f9b2b9002e8
~0x7f9b2ae004a8
~0x7f9b2af00268
~0x7f9b2b900338
~0x7f9b2af003c8
~0x7f9b2ae00608
~0x7f9b2af00528
~0x7f9b2ae00768
~0x7f9b2ae008c8
~0x7f9b2af00688
~0x7f9b2af006d8
~0x7f9b2ac02728
~0x7f9b2ae00128
~0x7f9b2b800128
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Comment: Does this still crash if instead of capturing the thread-scoped variable by reference in the lambda, the lambda calls a statically-scoped function, and then the function references the thread-scoped variable? The captured reference occurs in the main execution thread, but the captured reference gets used in each spawned execution thread, so the captured reference isn't really to an object in the scope of the execution thread. That seems to be the undefined behavior, here.

Comment: Yes, it still does ... good idea, though. Thanks for clarifying.

Just to verify I understand what you are trying to say:
https://pastebin.com/Qkau8Q77

Comment: I could not reproduce the crash (with either version of the code), with gcc 7.2.1 on Linux. Not really 100% sure that the capture of the reference constitutes use of the thread local variable.

Comment: I also couldn't reproduce it on Linux or Windows. It's just on MacOS with gcc ...